# NetSuite: Populate custom item field value on transaction custom column field

Tags: netsuite

I have 3 free-text custom fields on inventory item record. they contain different information based on location so my fields names are "XXXX Location1", "XXXX Location2" and "XXXX Location3". Across all transactions in the system we need to populate the information in a custom column field of these 3 fields based on the main location we choose on that transaction.

For example if on an Invoice the Main location is Location1 then our line custom column field should show information from "XXXX Location1" when user choose that item on the line; if Main location is Location2 on that Invoice then the line custom column field should show information from "XXXX Location2" when select that item on the line.

I understand this needs to be done thru scripts but i don't know how to write the script, could someone help?

Appreciate!!!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a script for that.
On the colmn field, set the field to be a formula.
In the formula, write the followin statement(change to real location names and real item custom field ids):

```
Case  {location} 
When "location1 name" then {item.custitem... }
When "location2 name" then {item.custitem.. }
When "location3 name" then {item.custitem...}
End
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help, formula is only for a default value. what we need is when user select a line item the line custom column field pop the relative information. i tried the formula but it is not working.

Comment: Hi,
Formula is not only for default value.
Make the formula field to be not stored, this way it will dynamically change on the fly.